# How to connect to a Web Socket Server hosted via Rust?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rust, tcp, openssl

I have a Web Socket Server written in Rust using `native_tls` because I need to eventually have it be able to receive connections remotely

```rs
use {
    native_tls::{Error as TlsError, HandshakeError, Identity, TlsAcceptor},
    std::{
        fs::File,
        io::{Error as IoError, Read},
        net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
        sync::Arc,
        thread::spawn,
    },
};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    IoError(IoError),
    TlsError(TlsError),
    HandshakeError(HandshakeError<TcpStream>),
}
impl From<IoError> for Error {
    fn from(error: IoError) -> Self {
        Self::IoError(error)
    }
}
impl From<TlsError> for Error {
    fn from(error: TlsError) -> Self {
        Self::TlsError(error)
    }
}
impl From<HandshakeError<TcpStream>> for Error {
    fn from(error: HandshakeError<TcpStream>) -> Self {
        Self::HandshakeError(error)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let identity = Identity::from_pkcs12(
        &{
            let mut identity = vec![];
            File::open("cert.p12")?.read_to_end(&mut identity)?;
            identity
        },
        "asdf",
    )?;

    let acceptor = Arc::new(TlsAcceptor::new(identity)?);

    for stream in TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:80")?.incoming() {
        let acceptor = acceptor.clone();

        spawn(move || -> Result<(), Error> {
            let client = acceptor.accept(stream?)?;
            println!("{:?}", client);
            Ok(())
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The javascript I use when attempting to connect:

```js
let socket = new WebSocket(`wss://127.0.0.1:80`);
```

Everything works just fine but when I go to connect to it via Javascript, the host reveives and accepts the connection but it is dropped instantaneously with:

```js
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://127.0.0.1:80/.
```

I'm still unfamiliar with both Javascript and Certificate handling with the `cert.p12` file.  To get this file, I followed a basic tutorial from [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/5.0.x?topic=profiles-generating-self-signed-certificate-using-openssl) but I'm not sure if this was the correct way of doing so.

Comment: You don't have a WebSocket server written in Rust, you have a TCP server. Are you mistakenly thinking those are the same? WebSocket is a protocol written on top of TCP.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Hmm ok well do you know of any way for writing Web Socket Servers in rust?

Comment: Have you looked into the crates available?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I have and I've decided to use `tungstenite` but when I attempt to connect to it using that crate, I get a `Insecure Connection` error though javascript.  I'm only confused with the difference between `ws` and `wss` because from my understanding, I thought `ws` was basically just `http` and `wss` is just `https` and that it needs a certificate and validation in order to be called "secure".

Comment: That is correct, `wss` is websocket over `https`. Have you configured `tungstenite` to use a TLS stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having is that `native_tls` wasn't able to work as a websocket itself.  It would need some other websocket implementation to work with such as [tungstenite](https://crates.io/crates/tungstenite).  When using `tungstenite`, in order to have `native_tls` and itself work together, I would host a normal Tcp Server but instead of accepting it through `tungstenite`, I would accept it with an acceptor from `native_tls` then afterwards accept the connection through `tungstenite` which would allow for a `tls` connection with access to `tungstenite`'s framework.